# How to clear an AWS Lambda cache (or force a cold start)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

**The short version:**

If I am caching values in my lambda container, how can I clear this cache? I guess I could redeploy the lambda, which will force all new requests to initiate a new cold start, but this doesn't seem like a nice solution.

**The long version:**

I am writing a custom authorizer for AWS API Gateway (in Python) that does two things:

1. It gets an api-key from an http header and looks it up in a dynamo table to verify it is valid (and get some attributes attached to it).
2. It verifies a JWT token (using some of the attributes from #1).

After following some code ([this code](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/blob/master/Cognito/decode-verify-jwt/decode-verify-jwt.py)), I learnt that I can cache values "globally" that can be re-used across invocations of the lambda, great! But if I cache say, the dynamodb response when looking up the api key, what if I have to revoke / issue a new api key at some point?
I'd like to be able to ensure that my lambda cache gets wiped somehow.

Comment: You can add your own logic to your code to delete or overwrite any global variables, when you decide you want to do this.

Comment: Instead of redeploying you can also update the function configuration via the CLI for example, so it's easily scriptable (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-configuration.html). Updating an environment variable is enough that the function gets replaced and therefore forces a cold start everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: You can force a new container for each invoke by calling the `UpdateFunctionCode` or `UpdateFunctionConfiguration` before exiting the execution for the same function. You can keep changing function time out before returning the response and the next invoke will spin up a new execution environment (container/sandbox) with a cold start penalty.

**The right approach**: If you are caching the function variables, you can clear them off inside the handler and continue with the execution logic. This will ensure you are not facing cold start penalties for subsequent invocations and you can in control of choosing the "right" values.

This can be better explained in using database clients. You can create the client outside the handler, but for every invoke verify if the client is valid. Recreate the client inside the handler if the original is now invalid. This will save you some processing time - as the [CPU is throttled](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddg1u5HLwg8&feature=youtu.be&t=683) when the function hits the handler.

Since you are working with API Gateway, the cold start penalties will contribute towards API's Integration timeout (hard limit of 29 seconds for auth and backend combined); and I will try to avoid forcing cold start as much as possible.

Comment: The point is to cache across invocations of the lambda, but be able to invalidate that cache somehow if the data changes. Forcing a cold start would be the same as not caching at all.

Comment: Lambda will freeze the execution context for future invokes when the container is still warm and when you are not concurrently invoking the function. Since the handler is always invoked for every invoke you would have to call DDB within the handler to always get the latest record.